# How to set environment variable to path stored in file

Tags: shell, sh

I'm writing a shell script to launch a program that requires an environment variable to be set in order to run it. 
I can run the program by typing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library" /path/to/program` into the shell, but I want the script to read both paths from files.

I have tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(cat path_to_library.txt) $(cat path_to_program.txt)` but this surrounds the path in quotes, and the program doesn't launch properly. Doing it directly like so: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=cat path_to_library.txt $(cat path_to_program.txt)` I get a permission denied error.
Surrounding the cat command in quotes just sets the variable to the literal text.
I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: what is the pupose of `..._PATH=$(cat file)`? do you know about "sourcing" a file. Any variables set in a sourced file are created in the enviroment of the calling script. so first line `#!/bin/bash` 2nd line `source /dir/with/files/LD_LIB_PATHsetter.txt`, 3rd line `source /dir/with/files/PATHsetter.txt` externalizes your settings, but will properly set the variables. Each file will contain settings like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:.....:....:....:` (path elements are separated by `:` chars. Same for `LD_LIB_PATH`. Good luck.

Comment: That works when I can change the contents of the files, but what can I do in case I cannot change the contents of the files, and they only contain the paths?
Your answer does work for my use case, but I'm just curious about this other case.

Comment: "but this surrounds the path in quotes" seems unlikely with the example commandline you provided at the start of the second paragraph

Comment: Huh, I can't seem to recreate the error now. I don't have a copy of what I had before I changed I used shellter's answer, but I definitely had some problem doing that before. I remember looking at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280892/command-substitution-cat-file-inserts-quotes), but I guess I just had a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: yes, worst case scenario is `export LD_LIB_PATH="$(< file1):$(< file2)"` (etc). but that is a real hack. Note that `$(< file)` notation reads the contents of `file`, and "displays" it to the command-substitution ( `$(...)` ) that surrounds it. It saves you a process creation that you "spend" when you call `cat`. ;-) . As noted by @jhnc your sample in 2nd paragraph will not work as an assignment to any variable, because of the space char between the two `$(cmd-substitutions)`. Good luck.

Comment: You mush use the form of `VAR="elements with spaces"` for any variable assignment where the value has space(s). So if you have a windows(ish) path with spaces in a directory name, you need to dbl-quote that value. Good look.